# How to add some tags to html using linux commands like sed

Tags: html, linux, sed

I have html page with some tables and I need add new table as FIRST table on the page using bash script, I know that it can be done using sed or smt else, but I dont know how it working... Can someone help to find way for it?

example of html page:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>

THERE SHOULD BE ADDED NEW TABLE ROW LIKE BELOW 


<tr>
<td rowspan="2" bgcolor="#fff1cc" class="style4"><div align="center">
<h4>2012-07-17</h4>
</div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td height="2" bgcolor="#fff1cc" class="style4"><a ref="07_17_ef47efb/index.html">sha1:ef47efb</a></td>
<td bgcolor="#fff1cc" class="style4" align="center"><img src="../Pictures/green.gif" width="35" height="37"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td rowspan="2" bgcolor="#fff1cc" class="style4"><div align="center">
<h4>2012-07-17</h4>
</div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td height="2" bgcolor="#fff1cc" class="style4"><a href="07_17_ef47efb/index.html">sha1:ef47efb</a></td>
<td bgcolor="#fff1cc" class="style4" align="center"><img src="../Pictures/green.gif" width="35" height="37"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td rowspan="2" bgcolor="#fff1cc" class="style4"><div align="center">
<h4>2012-07-17</h4>
</div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td height="2" bgcolor="#fff1cc" class="style4"><a href="07_17_ef47efb/index.html">sha1:ef47efb</a></td>
<td bgcolor="#fff1cc" class="style4" align="center"><img src="../Pictures/green.gif" width="35" height="37"></td>
</tr>
</body>
</html>
```

exmaple of Table row  that should be added as FIRST in html page:

```
<tr>
<td rowspan="2" bgcolor="#fff1cc" class="style4"><div align="center">
<h4>$date</h4>
</div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td height="2" bgcolor="#fff1cc" class="style4"><a ref="$path/index.html">sha1:$rev</a></td>
<td bgcolor="#fff1cc" class="style4" align="center"><img src="../Pictures/green.gif" width="35" height="37"></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

1) your html has no `<table></table>` is it right?

2) if the rows you want to add are fixed, you could save them into a file, say rows.txt. then try to replace the `<body>` tag with `<body>` and the content of your rows.txt. However, if there are nested `<table>`s in your foo.html. it could be complicated.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution - [SED: change/insert/append lines after matching a pattern](http://mohammednv.wordpress.com/2009/11/15/sed-changeinsertappend-lines-after-matching-a-pattern/).